# MVC Razor .CheckboxFor not binded as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've tried both CheckboxFor and EditorFor to bind a checkbox to the model.
The issue is that it's always unchecked and it does not seem to reflect the true/false value from the model.

View

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsConfirmed)
```

Result in browser

```
<input name="IsConfirmed" id="IsConfirmed" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
<input name="IsConfirmed" type="hidden" value="false"/>
```

View

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.IsConfirmed)
```

Result in browser

```
<input name="IsConfirmed" class="check-box" id="IsConfirmed" type="checkbox" data-val="true" value="true"/>
<input name="IsConfirmed" type="hidden" value="false"/>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `CheckBoxFor` should work fine, are you sure you Model value is being set correctly?

Comment: Examining the model, the value is present in the controller, but it's lost in the view. So you're correct that this is an issue in my view and not the CheckboxFor. Thanks :)

Comment: I am having this exact issue, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @musefan commented, the issue is with my view and not the HtmlHelper.

The issue boiled down to "chain-of-events". The view was binded post-load by ajax, and the value for the checkbox was not set up for this call.

Comment: If you get the chance, try and post a bit more info once you solve the problem as to why you had the issue and how you fixed it. Might help somebody else in the future ;)